# Apache manipulating query string on https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

the following rules works on http but don't on https.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "page=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [L]
RewriteRule ^/path/file.html$ https://www.domain.tld/path/file/ [R=301,L]
```

Why the query_string part doesn't work in https?

Comment: Are these the only rules you've got?

Comment: no, after I've some 301 redirect in this way: RewriteRule ^/path/file.html$ https://www.domain.tld/path/file/ [R=301,L]

Comment: What is the point of `RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [L]`?

Comment: to remove all the get parameters

Comment: what do you mean by not working , does it redirect the url to an unexpected location ?

Comment: I mean that it doesn't remove the get parameters (?page=1&other=2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of your question, it appears that you just want to remove the query string anytime there is a page parameter. This type of rewrite rule doesn't strip off or change the URL unless there is a redirect. So if you don't add `R=301` or `R` to the rewrite rule, the query string will not be removed. All of the following worked on my server to remove the query string, and my server is 100% HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "page=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Or you may be able to use the QSD flag instead of question mark:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "page=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Or you may be able to use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "page=" [NC]
RewriteRule .* /? [R=301,L]
```

Or just R (for 302) instead of R=301:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "page=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R,L]
```

But in no case was the query string removed unless I used a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Really all you need is **QSD** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.htm

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "page=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1 [L,QSD]
```

I'm not sure why it would work on http but not https unless you're using separate vhosts for http and https and the settigns were slightly different

Remember that Rewrite rules are internal unless using the R flag. When you use the R flag it tells the browser to go to a different page causing a full server/client round-trip. Otherwise, it just changes the request and proceeds as normal.

Comment: Can you define didn't work? If you are looking in your browser at the URI then it's not going to change as I mentioned unless you use the R flag. Are you saying that the query string is still available in whatever you are using downstream of Apache (php, python, other cgi)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really strong with .htaccess file, and I can't explain what's going on behind the scenes, but from my opinion your .htaccess file should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page= [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [L]
RewriteRule ^path/file.html$ https://www.domain.tld/path/file/ [R=301,L]
```

It work perfectly for

```
http://example.com?page=1
https://example.com/?page=1
http://example.com/path/file.html
https://example.com/path/file.html
```

Tested (with love) [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: Ahaha, if no one of suggested answers not work, probably you have other problem. Try to reinstall apache, or provide more details. Think you have one small option or directive somewhere in apache configuration files, and nobody can help you.